# Mongo throws E11000 duplicate key error whey I try to do db.collection.save operation on array of docs

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to call mongodb's db.collection.save method with array of documents as parameter. I'd like to do bulk operation insert/replace if _id exists.

Here is my test case:

```
> use sometestdb
switched to db sometestdb
> 
> doc1 = { _id: 1, value: "some value 1" }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : "some value 1" }
> doc2 = { _id: 2, value: "some value 2" }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : "some value 2" }
> doc3 = { _id: 3, value: "some value 3" }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : "some value 3" }
> 
> db.docs.save( [doc1, doc2, doc3] )
> 
> doc1 = { _id: 1, value: "some value 1 - updated" }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : "some value 1 - updated" }
> doc2 = { _id: 2, value: "some value 2 - updated" }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : "some value 2 - updated" }
> doc3 = { _id: 3, value: "some value 3 - updated" }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : "some value 3 - updated" }
> db.docs.save( [doc1, doc2, doc3] )
E11000 duplicate key error index: sometestdb.docs.$_id_  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

If I try to call `db.docs.save (doc1)`, `db.docs.save (doc2)` then no error is thrown. Thx.

Comment: `save` isn't documented as supporting arrays. Use `insert`. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/ for the original insert. Beyond that, you can't batch update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this is a bug. It is strange, but the official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) does not tell anything regarding using save with array of documents. It just states about 1 document:

> Updates an existing document or inserts a new document, depending on
>   its document parameter.

So may be this is an undocumented feature that you can pass an array :-)

Diving deeper, you can see that save is implemented in the following way:

```
function ( obj ){
    if ( obj == null || typeof( obj ) == "undefined" )
        throw "can't save a null";

    if ( typeof( obj ) == "number" || typeof( obj) == "string" )
        throw "can't save a number or string"

    if ( typeof( obj._id ) == "undefined" ){
        obj._id = new ObjectId();
        return this.insert( obj );
    }
    else {
        return this.update( { _id : obj._id } , obj , true );
    }
}
```

What is interesting for us is the third if:

```
    if ( typeof( obj._id ) == "undefined" ){
        obj._id = new ObjectId();
        return this.insert( obj );
    }
```

When you pass your `[doc1, doc2, doc3]` for the first time, your `typeof( [doc1, doc2, doc3]._id )` is `undefined`, so it perform `insert`. And `insert` inserts an array element by element.

The problem is that when you are passing it for the next time, it is still undefined and also performs insert and gets the error as a duplicated key. But if you would be saving just one document, this third block would not return undefined and thus perform an update.

*Nonetheless right now it is understandable why is it performing in such a way, I think that documentation is ambiguous.*

Anyway, you can achieve what you want with the following:

```
var list = [doc1, doc2, doc3] ;
for (var i =0; i< list.length; i++){
  db.docs.save(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I create an issue in their JIRA https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-2191. Will see what is correct :)

Comment: Interesting conclusion "trying to use code in an undocumented way and it doesn't work = bug". Code used in an undocumented way that doesn't work is almost always user error.

Answer (score 3):

Batch updates to multiple documents in a single call is not supported in MongoDB. While the behavior may seem unusual, the console's JavaScript is partially trying to perform exactly what you are asking, even though I'd suspect it's unintentional, as using `insert` would be more efficient in the first case.

When you:

```
db.docs.save( [doc1, doc2, doc3] )
```

MongoDB loops through the array and creates each document:

```
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : "some value 1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : "some value 2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : "some value 3" }
```

If you were to repeat this operation, you're finding that:

```
> db.docs.save([doc1,doc2,doc3])
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.docs.$_id_  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

This makes at least partial sense, as you cannot `insert` the same document twice in a collection:

```
> db.docs.insert(doc1)
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.docs.$_id_  dup key: { : 1.0 }
```

As there is no efficient "batch" update in MongoDB for multiple documents (you can update multiple documents at one time that all match a single query, but you cannot update individual documents by passing in an array, at least through the console).

`save` is just a helper method around update as it extracts the `_id` from the document and passes it through to `update`.

So, while they could add functionality as a convenience method to the console support, the underlying MongoDB database still would not have direct support for the operation, so it would still perform the operations individually. Some drivers already support that -- but it's done one by one rather than as a batch.

The equivalent of your desired behavior could be written in one line anyway:

```
[doc1, doc2, doc3].forEach(function(d) { db.docs.save(d) })
```

Comment: So basically you rewrote what I wrote an hour ago?