# Duplicate Key Error - MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, key, duplicates

I am parsing XML in a console application and trying to insert into a MongoDB instance in C# using the Mongo Nuget package (version 1.8.3.9) using the

```
Collection.Insert(model)
```

method. I keep getting the error

**mongodb WriteConcern detected an error 'E11000 duplicate key error index**

I am inserting the documents sequentially, one at a time and it would seem to me that this would be a timing issue but then again, I'm brand new at MongoDB.

I see [previous stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787803/mongo-throws-e11000-duplicate-key-error-whey-i-try-to-do-db-collection-save-oper) stating to update to the 1.8.1 version but I am currently using a newer version than this so that doesn't seem to be the solution.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this before and might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your database has a column marked as unique. Your data has duplicates in that column, either within the data or duplicates of data already in the table. Since you have posted neither data nor schema I can't suggest where to look.

Comment: You are correct. I figured it out after posting this. I was trying to reuse the model object instead of creating a new instance. It seems that when the model is inserted it has an ObjectID applied to it which it then tries to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Always instantiate object of your model before insertion into Mongo inside the foreach loop
Example:

```cs
#Model
public class Employee()
{
public string Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}

List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

foreach(var emp in empList)
{
  ///Always create a new object before insertion as duplicate id for the same object might create a problem.
   var info =  new List<Employee>();
   info.Add(emp);
  await _employeeDetailsRepository.InsertOneAsync(info);
}
```